# In Excel, how to round to nearest fibonacci number

Tags: excel, rounding, worksheet-function, fibonacci

In Excel, I would like to round to the nearest fibonacci  number.

I tried something like (sorry with a french Excel):

```
RECHERCHEH(C7;FIBO;1;VRAI) -- HLOOKUP(C7, FIBO, 1, TRUE)
```

where FIBO is a named range (0; 0,5; 1;2;3;5;8;etc.)

my problem is that this function rounds to the smallest number and not the nearest. For example 12.8 is rounded to 8 and not 13.

Note: I just want to use an excel formula, and no VBA

Comment: Why do you have 0.5 as a Fibonacci number?

Comment: Well, this is a pseudo fibonacci list used by agilists to estimate user stories weight. It also includes 20 40 and 100 (or infinite)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This will work:

```
=INDEX(FIBO,1, IF(C7>=(INDEX(FIBO,1,(MATCH(C7,FIBO,1)))+
    INDEX(FIBO,1,(MATCH(C7,FIBO,1)+1)))/2, MATCH(C7,FIBO,1)+1, MATCH(C7,FIBO,1)))
```

Comment: Wow ! Thanks.
Translated in french Excel for those who might be interested : 

=INDEX(FIBO;1; SI(C7>=(INDEX(FIBO;1;(EQUIV(C7;FIBO;1)))+INDEX(FIBO;1;(EQUIV(C7;FIBO;1)+1)))/2; EQUIV(C7;FIBO;1)+1; EQUIV(C7;FIBO;1)))

Comment: Thanks! Translated in spanish Excel: =INDICE(FIBO;1; SI(B3>=(INDICE(FIBO;1;(COINCIDIR(B3;FIBO;1)))+INDICE(FIBO;1;(COINCIDIR(B3;FIBO;1)+1)))/2; COINCIDIR(B3;FIBO;1)+1; COINCIDIR(B3;FIBO;1))) FIBO is a named range in horizontal cells

Comment: Thanks! Translated in portuguese Excel: `=ÍNDICE(FIBO,1,SE(C7>=(ÍNDICE(FIBO,1,(CORRESP(C7,FIBO,1)))+ÍNDICE(FIBO,1,(CORRESP(C7,FIBO,1)+1)))/2,CORRESP(C7,FIBO,1)+1,CORRESP(C7,FIBO,1)))`

Comment: Thanks for this! I did something similar but I only wanted to round up, which actually makes the formula simpler (but it does require reverse-sorting your range of point values): `=INDEX(FIBO, 1, MATCH(C7, FIBO, -1))`

Comment: Thanks! Translated in german Excel: =INDEX(FIBO;1; WENN(B15>=(INDEX(FIBO;1;(VERGLEICH(B15;FIBO;1)))+INDEX(FIBO;1;(VERGLEICH(B15;FIBO;1)+1)))/2; VERGLEICH(B15;FIBO;1)+1; VERGLEICH(B15;FIBO;1)))

Answer (score 2):

Define the target number Targ, relative to which we want to find the closest Fib number.

Define

```
n = INT(LN(Targ*SQRT(5))/LN((1+SQRT(5))/2))
```

It follows that Fib(n) <= Targ <= Fib(n+1)

where one can compute Fib(n) and Fib(n+1) via

```
Fib(n) = ROUND(((1+SQRT(5))/2)^n/SQRT(5),0)
```

Finally find the closest Fib number to Targ using the computed values of Fib(n) and Fin(n+1).

Not as compact as the other solution presented since it requires a few helper formulas, but it requires no table for Fib numbers.

Comment: What about lucas numbers? What would that formula look like?

Comment: @JonLennartAasenden You can abuse the special property of the Lucas numbers to get any term after the first two: `=ROUND(((1+SQRT(5))/2)^SEQUENCE(20,,2),0)` will list the 20 terms after the first two.

Answer (score 0):

I used a simpler nested IF solution.

I calculated the mid point between each pair of Fibonacci numbers and used that as the decision point. The following tests the value in A2 to produce the desired Fibonacci number:

```vb
=IF(A2>=30,40,IF(A2>=16.5,20,IF(A2>=10.5,13,IF(A2>=6.5,8,IF(A2>=4,5,IF(A2>=2.5,3,IF(A2>=1.5,2,IF(A2>=0.5,1,0))))))))
```